# React native Android SyntaxError attempted to redefine property 'FileSystem'

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I get the following error on my android device after upgrade react native to 0.46.1 .
I using expo to build react native project , i dont know how to fixed it , it take me a lot of time
[image]

this is my package.json:

```
 {
        "name": "my-project",
        "version": "0.1.0",
        "private": true,
        "devDependencies": {
        "babel-eslint": "^7.2.1",
        "babel-jest": "19.0.0",
        "babel-plugin-flow-react-proptypes": "^0.21.0",
        "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
        "babel-preset-react-native": "^1.9.1",
        "babel-preset-react-native-stage-0": "^1.0.1",
        "eslint": "^3.18.0",
        "eslint-config-airbnb": "^14.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-babel": "^4.1.1",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.2.0",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^4.0.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.10.3",
        "flow-bin": "^0.38.0",
        "jest": "19.0.2",
        "jest-expo": "1.0.1",
        "react-native-scripts": "0.0.29",
        "react-test-renderer": "^15.6.1"
    },
    "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-native-scripts start",
        "eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
        "android": "react-native-scripts android",
        "ios": "react-native-scripts ios",
        "test": "node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watch"
    },
    "jest": {
        "preset": "jest-expo"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.16.1",
        "expo": "^19.0.0-alpha.0",
        "lodash.debounce": "^4.0.8",
        "lodash.isempty": "^4.4.0",
        "mobx": "^3.1.9",
        "mobx-react": "^4.1.8",
        "native-base": "2.2.1",
        "qs": "^6.4.0",
        "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
        "react-native": "0.46.1",
        "react-native-easy-grid": "^0.1.11",
        "react-native-fs": "^2.3.3",
        "react-native-modalbox": "^1.3.9",
        "react-native-radio-buttons": "^0.14.0",
        "react-native-storage": "^0.2.2",
        "react-native-svg": "^5.3.0",
        "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.9",
        "singleton": "^1.0.0",
        "styled-components": "^1.4.6"
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to show us the code.

Comment: Yeah, my crystal ball isn't working either.